# mongo aggregation sum on a field while the values of the field should map to +/- according to anther field

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongo-shell

I have the following `collection` in `mongodb`,

```
doc_id    amount    memo
1         1.0       P
1         2.0       N
2         3.0       P
2         4.0       P
2         5.0       N
```

I want to `sum` the `amount` field that `P` in `memo` indicates a positive value, `N` indicates a negative value for values of `amount`; so when I `group` the `doc_id` and do the `sum`, I will get `-1.0` for `doc_id` `1`, and `2.0` for `doc_id` `2`. I know how to group by `doc_id` and then `sum`,

```
db.collection.aggregate({ $group: { _id : 'doc_id', sum: { $sum: "$amount"}}});
```

but don't know how to take `P` and `N` into account here.

Answer (score 3):

Use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) to project the values as negative/positive based on memo, and then sum the amount.
The following query written in pymongo will work for you.

```
db.collection..aggregate([{'$project': 
                           {'amount': {'$cond': { 'if': { '$eq':['$memo','P'] }, 'then': '$amount', 
                                                'else': {'$multiply':['$amount',-1]} }},
                            'doc_id': '$doc_id'}},
                         {'$group': {'_id': '$doc_id','sum':{'$sum': '$amount'}}}])
```